# Read out subfolder of inbox using exchangelib

Tags: python, exchangelib

is it possible to read out the body of an email that is in a subfolder of the inbox using exchangelib? If yes, how can I achieve that?
I only know that I can get the body of an email which is in the inbox using the following code:

```
for item in account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:1]:
    print(item.body)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. See the folder navigation options described in https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib#folders

Here's an example:

```
sub_sub_folder = account.inbox / 'Some' / 'Subfolder'
for item in sub_sub_folder.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:1]:
    print(item.body)
```